# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called in foreground firebase cloud messaging for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to implement firebase cloud messaging on my app.

I register the notification using the following codes

```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
```

Everything works fine when the app is in the back ground, but when the app is in the foreground, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called at all.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Print message ID.
    print("please help")
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Anyone knows possible error with this? Thanks!

EDIT: I do not need to see a notification display when the app is in foreground, I merely want to handle the message from the notification

Comment: is this completion handler not calling at all?

Comment: Declare UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate or not?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10.x has a new function that handles push notification when in foreground, you should implement this one:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(
        [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,
         UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please implement below method to receive push notifications in foreground

**For iOS10, Swift3:**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) 
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

For **iOS10, Swift 2.3:**

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    //Handle the notification
    completionHandler(
       [UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert,
        UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound,
        UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge])
}
```

Try this once:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Recived: \(userInfo)")

    completionHandler(.NewData)

}
```

Comment: where do i implement this method? Btw, how about iOS 9 and below?

Comment: Implement this in appdelegate. For iOS9 and below you don't need this method

Comment: in iOS9 check wether, it's working or not. It should work I think.

Comment: No, not `AppDelegate`, put it in `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

Comment: @SivajeeBattina thanks for the response., sorry but i don need the notification display.. I merely want to handle the notification message, that is why i want to call didReceiveNotficaition delegate method.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina yes,it displays a notification when the app is in the foreground.. but i wish to handle the message sent to the app rather than displaying the notification banner.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Push Notification Firebase for IOS 10. 
Please add this code. Hope to help you solve this problem :

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```